# Couldn't generate Swift representation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, carthage

I use Carthage and I get the error Couldn't generate Swift representation when I touch import module in own class. I tried several libraries and I got the same result. I wrote [there](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/921) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894901/xcode-couldnt-generate-swift-representation-for-my-own-framework) but it didn't help me.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rename the project folder from Development for iOS to Development.

Comment: Which project folder ? Can you explain more how it was solved ?

Comment: For future reference: This error seems to occur due to Xcode not handling spaces in paths well. For me, renaming my xcodeproj and target name to not include any spaces did the trick.