# Type does not conform to protocol 'ImagePickerDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift, types

I'm using a library called [ImagePicker](https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker) from github to get images from the user and upload them. However when i implement the sample code, [found here](https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker/blob/master/Demo/ImagePickerDemo/ImagePickerDemo/ViewController.swift), i get the following error:

Type 'changeCoverViewController' does not conform to protocol 'ImagePickerDelegate'

on line one of the code:

```
class changeCoverViewController: UIViewController, ImagePickerDelegate {
```

Comment: cmd+click on `ImagePickerDelegate` you will be directed to library where its protocols have been declared, add those function's in this viewController

Comment: When i cmd+click on ImagePickerDelegate it says "Couldn't generate swift representation" "Error (from SourceKit): Could not load module: ImagePicker" @Dravidian

Comment: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/921

Answer (score 5):

You are probably missing one of the required `ImagePickerDelegate` functions. Specifically these:

```
func wrapperDidPress(imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage])
func doneButtonDidPress(imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage])
func cancelButtonDidPress(imagePicker: ImagePickerController)
```

---

In the future if you notice this error again go to the declaration of the delegate and you'll see a class `protocol` and that'll tell you what is required to implement said delegate. In this case:

```
public protocol ImagePickerDelegate: class {
  func wrapperDidPress(imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage])
  func doneButtonDidPress(imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage])
  func cancelButtonDidPress(imagePicker: ImagePickerController)
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to find the declaration of the delegates, and when i cmd+click on ImagePickerDelegate it says "Couldn't generate swift representation" "Error (from SourceKit): Could not load module: ImagePicker"

Comment: Could this be due to using Carthage

Comment: Carthage is another question then. Might want to look at this answer @user4174219, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894901/xcode-couldnt-generate-swift-representation-for-my-own-framework