# Unable to debug a framework in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, debugging, frameworks, xcode8, sourcekit

I have a framework project I built in debug mode. I added such resulting framework to another iOS project. My iOS project builds correctly and the framework is called, I get its methods results. However, some of the results are not the expected and I need to debug the framework's code from the iOS project.

I am also running the iOS project in debug mode and setting a breakpoint at the framework's method call I want to debug. But "step into" instruction in the debugger does not enter into the framework's code. In addition, if I "command-click" the name of the method to try to go to its code, I get an:

> Couldn't Generate Swift Representation

My issue is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894901/xcode-couldnt-generate-swift-representation-for-my-own-framework), but the answer there is not working for me. Is somebody experiencing the same? Could somebody provide another solution?

Comment: Can you make a sample project that shows this error available to us?  It's hard to figure out what's wrong in the abstract.  If you can, please file a bug with http://bugreporter.apple.com.  Thanks!

Comment: If you are not using a combined Xcode workspace with the two projects in the workspace, you might try that.  Xcode can better manage the debug information between projects if they are in a shared workspace.

Comment: @JimIngham thank you, I'll try that. Which is the appropriate way to add the framework project to the main app project for this purpose, should I have to take care of any particular settings?

Comment: I think the simplest way to do this is to make an Xcode Workspace (File->New->Workspace) then add the two projects to the workspace.  Here's an introduction to how workspaces work: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html